# Turning off i3lock

Tags: linux, manjaro, i3-window-manager

So I'm using i3wm on my Manjaro for 2 days or so. The thing that really annoys me is the fact that whenever I go afk for like 5/10 minutes, the screen gets blurred and I have to type my password (a circle appears in the middle of the screen) and click `ENTER`. I know this is caused by `i3lock`. In `xfce4-power-manager-settings` I've got everything set to `Never` (blurring, powering off etc.). How can I turn this option off, just to make my screen not blurr itself?

Comment: `i3wm` doesn't usually use settings from other desktop environments.  check your `.config/i3/config` for `i3lock`-related lines, especially `exec` lines that run [`xautolock`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Screensaver_and_power_management) or [`xss-lock`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#xss-lock) or similar.  if that doesn't help, edit your post to include your i3 config so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: `#exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 10 -locker blurlock` I guess that was the problematic line. Thanks!

Comment: Either of you (FrynioS / quixotic) should add that as an answer if it works!